# Combine two queries into one in same table (same columns/different rows)

Tags: mysql

For a messaging system, I'm trying to mark the appropriate to_del and from_del fields for employee 2.

Here is before employee 2 deletes messages:

```
company_id | to | from | to_del | from_del
    1        4     2       0         0
    1        2     4       0         0
```

Here is after employee 2 deletes messages:

```
company_id | to | from | to_del | from_del
    1        4     2       0         1
    1        2     4       1         0
```

I have to run 2 queries for this to work:

```
UPDATE messages SET from_del='1' WHERE company_id=1 AND from=2
UPDATE messages SET to_del='1' WHERE company_id=1 AND to=2
```

Is there anyway to merge these 2 queries into 1 more efficient query? Something like:

```
UPDATE messages SET from_del='1',to_del='1' WHERE company_id=1 AND (from=2 OR to=2)
```

This single query's issue is that it marks all 4 delete fields as '1'. Any ideas on how to get a single efficient query to act like the 2 above queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)...

```
update messages
   set from_del = case when from = 2 then 1 else from_del end
     , to_del = case when to = 2 then 1 else to_del end
 where company_id = '1'
```

You're updating columns that don't need to be this way, but you're only performing one update not multiple as you would with multiple queries.

I dislike the use of `from` and `to` as column names... It just asking for confusion...

Comment: Thanks for your input, but what do you mean by 'You're updating columns that don't need to be this way'?

Comment: It means that if you only need to update `from_del` you're also going to update `to_del` whether you like it or not, you update it to the same value if it doesn't match your condition, but you still update it.

Comment: is that the else from_del and else to_del? Do you think it's more efficient to run two queries like above or use the case part?

Comment: The query basically updates each column with itself if there's nothing to do. You will have to change it slightly each time. Whether it's more efficient or not depends entirely on your database. I can only say probably :-). It should definitely be quicker. `messages` is index on company_id?

Comment: No index yet. It just sucks that you MUST update the value to itself instead of leaving it alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're performing an update that requires two different `WHERE` clauses, then unfortunately you will have to perform two queries. If you are worried about performance, you could always batch them in a single `TRANSACTION`.